# Permission denied for writing in sshfs with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, file-permissions, sshfs

I am trying to mount a sshfs for a service. There is my Docker Stack config:

```
...
myservice:
...
    volumes:
      - "sshfs_volume:/home/app/web/media:rw"
...
volumes:
  sshfs_volume:
    driver: vieux/sshfs:latest
    driver_opts:
      sshcmd: "username@myhost:shared_storage"
      allow_other: ""
      password: "*****"
```

The command "ls -la /home/app/web/media" in a container returns the following result:

```
total 12
drwxrwxr-x    1 1000     1001          4096 Aug  9 21:55 .
drwxr-sr-x    1 app      app           4096 Aug  9 21:54 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1001             0 Aug  9 21:55 dump
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1001             0 Aug  9 21:17 tmp.txt
```

This files were created by me via sshfs command in the same host where docker container was running. It means that volume was mounted correctly (maybe excepting permission issues).

The problem is that i can't write files in containers in this volume. For example:

```
> touch /home/app/web/media/t2.txt

touch: /home/app/web/media/t2.txt: Permission denied
```

I have tried to restart Docker Daemon, remove volumes and recreate them. The result is the same, it didn't help.

Comment: The `ls -l` listing suggests that directory is writable by user 1000 and group 1001.  Does that match the (numeric) user and group IDs your container has; probably a Compose `user:` declaration?

Comment: No, `id` returned `uid=100(app) gid=101(app) groups=101(app)`. Also i don't have `user:` declaration.

Comment: I ran `docker exec -u 1001:1001 container touch /home/app/web/media/t2.txt` and it worked.

Comment: I solved it by adding to my service this parameter: `user: "100:101"` and adding this parameters to the volume: `uid: 100` and `gid: 101` in the docker-stack file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding to my service this parameter: `user: "100:101"` and adding this parameters to the volume: `uid: 100` and `gid: 101` in the docker-stack file. My final docker-stack file:

```
...
myservice:
...
    user: "100:101"
    volumes:
      - "sshfs_volume:/home/app/web/media:rw"
...
volumes:
  sshfs_volume:
    driver: vieux/sshfs:latest
    driver_opts:
      sshcmd: "username@myhost:shared_storage"
      allow_other: ""
      default_permissions: ""
      reconnect: ""
      uid: 100
      gid: 101
      password: "*****"
```